# How to register a Service programmatically in Android?

Tags: java, android, service, android-manifest, registration

**Android version: Android 10**

If TestService is not defined in the "AndroidManifest.xml", then we can't use "**context.startService(new Intent(context, TestService.class))**" to start the service.

It should be related to the service registration.

**Case Study:** 
I want to load a jar at runtime, and that jar contains some services. I don't want to define all services inside the "AndroidManifest.xml".

**Question 1:**
Is it possible to register the TestService programmatically before starting it? If yes, how to do?

**Question 2:**
If dynamic service registration is impossible, then why can Android dynamically register the service which defined in AndroidManifest.xml?

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application
    ...

    <!--
    <service
        android:name=".service.TestService"/>
    -->

    ...

</application>
```

**TestService.java**

```
public class TestService extends IntentService {
    ...
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
        System.out.println("------ TestService onHandleIntent ------");
    }
    ...
}
```

**TestActivity.java**

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        test(getContext());
    }
});

public static void test(Context context) {
    context.startService(new Intent(context, TestService.class));
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: bear in mind that your app will be banned from the Play Store (and perhaps some other distribution channels) --- May I know is loading jar at runtime not allowed by Google?

Comment: See https://play.google.com/intl/en-US/about/privacy-security-deception/malicious-behavior/.

Comment: I have read that article. If loading jar not allowed, then is it related to this statement:       Likewise, an app may not download executable code (e.g. dex, JAR, .so files) from a source other than Google Play

Comment: Correct. "The following are explicitly prohibited... Apps or SDKs that download executable code, such as dex files or native code, from a source other than Google Play."

Comment: Thanks for your reminding me.

Comment: all comments here are unhelpful and do not answer the question adequately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check here to get more detail https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro#components

> For each app component that you create in your app, you must declare a corresponding XML element in the manifest file:
>   If you subclass any of these components without declaring it in the manifest file, the system cannot start it.

Basiclly, when you start any component android start it by android system not inside your application. Additional android support start activity or bind service from other applicationa so you must declare in AndroidManifest to tell other apps

Comment: Thank you, is the Context.startService an RPC call to the Android system?